# How to get name of System.Xml.Linq.XNode?

Tags: c#, xml, casting

Each XML element, like `<title />` has a name - "title".
I use foreach to enumerate items supplied by **XNode.Nodes()** method and handle each of them by tag name.

I cast XNode to XElement, to access **XElement.Name.LocalName** property to get tag name, like "title".

```
foreach(XElement as_element in doc.Nodes())
```

Problem has appeared after i have tried parsing this tag:

```
<title>"Some text"</title>
```

Now its type is XText (: XNode), and i cannot cast it to XElement. I get an InvalidCastException.
How can i get XNode's "name"?

Comment: what do you mean by name? what should be the name of "Some text" ? it isn't an element so it doesn't have a name.

Comment: Name of tag )element, node) is "title". I need that in my code, but XNode has no property of type XName.

Comment: you mean you need to get "title" from "Some Text" ?

Comment: I need to get "title" from <title>ANYTHING</title>

Comment: The `XElement` has the `Name` property. Where is the problem?

Comment: That Nodes() return XNode, and XNode is not based on XElement.

Comment: `foreach(XElement as_element in doc.Nodes())` Now `as_element` is an `XElement`.

Comment: well then don't use Nodes if you dont wanna work with Nodes, use Elements or Descendants methods.

Comment: @Selman22 Yeah i switched to using Elements() and problem gone, as now i get pure XElements. But i still do not uderstand how to get name of XNode, it MUST have a name, like any node in XML?

Comment: so I need to repeat my question, what should be the name of "Some Text", it's just a TEXT. it doesn't have any name.

Comment: @Selman22 It has a name because it is a node, which name is `"title"`, and `"some text"` is its Value. I use `Nodes()` on `XElement`, which is parent for `<title>"some"</title>`. Why i can't get a name of this sub-node, why do i have only ability to read its text. I think i do not understand difference between 'elements' and 'nodes' properly.

Comment: no title has nothing to do with that. title is another node, it's an element node and completely separate node from the "Some Text". it's just the parent node of the "Some Text". So it has a name because it's an Element. A text node does not have any name.

Comment: @Selman22 i was ready to mark your answer as solution. Your info was important for me. I had no knowledge of exact difference between a node and an element.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

INode does not always have a name. It's better to use `Elements()` instead of `Nodes()`, to enumerate child elements inside XElement, then we have a `IEnumerable<XElement>`.

Comment: and what if you want iterate all nodes, include text, and if its an element you want know his name?

Answer (score -1):

if you have a node of element type, you can cast it:

```
if (node.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) {
    var el = (XElement)node;
    Console.WriteLine(el.Name);
}
```

Comment: Find any open XML dataset, write nested loop with your code, and you will provide yourself with anything necessary.